# Interactive Map and Lat Lon Input Interface in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet, rshiny

Here's what I tried

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        fitBounds(-124.7666, 49.4000, -67.0583, 25.0666)%>%
        setView(-95.91245, 37.2333, zoom = 3)
    })
    
    click = input$mymap_click
    if(is.null(click))
      return()
    
    leafletProxy('mymap')%>%addMarkers(lng = click$lng,
                                       lat = click$lat)%>%
      setView(lng = click$lng,
              lat = click$lat, zoom =7)
    
    output$text <- renderText(paste(click$lng,click$lat))
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(textOutput("text"),
                leafletOutput("mymap"))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But instead of a reactive output text, I want something which is dynamic i.e., map should change with change in lat, lon value and vice versa

Here's a sample representation from  https://psl.noaa.gov/eddi/
[image: Here's a sample representation]

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is for the map to center on the clicked marker, move the lines from `click = ...` to `setView` in its own `observeEvent()`. Also, you do not need to wrap everything in an `observe()`.

```
server <- function {
  output$mapmap <- renderLeaflet(...)

  observeEvent(input$mymap_click) {
    click = ...
    ...
    leafletProxy(...) %>%
      setView(...)

  }

  output$text <- renderText(...)

}
```

Comment: Maybe I got my wording wrong. I am precisely looking for both map and lat lon interface to be reactive to each other, i.e.

1. If we input lat and long value (as an input interface) it should add as a marker on the map Also, 
2. If we click on the map, it should show the lat and long value (in the input interface itself) of the marker on the map.